# Jabref external PDF viewer not working with newly added papers

Tags: bibtex, pdf, jabref

I've been using Jabref for a while and linking files so that I can just click the PDF icon on the left to open the relevant papers (or use shift+F5 etc). But lately when I add new pdf's they won't open. The "Status" bar at the bottom says "External viewer called," but they never show up.

As mentioned the files added to my bibtex file earlier work fine. They way I add the files is the same as ever (drag them onto the "File" field of the "General" tab), and looking at the bibtex code it also looks the same.

It's annoying to have to go to my references folder and find the file for all new papers. Anyone else have this issue?

PS: I use windows 7 and my PDF viewer is Foxit Reader. I tried upgrading to the newest version of Jabref.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with the reader calling settings and unfortunately seems offtopic for us. Nevertheless you can ask this on foxit or jabref forums